How to find file names but only with grep .html OR .php?
This works fine:
find . -type f -name "*dan*" | grep '.html'

But how to add one more to grep? With OR ? -o ?
find . -type f -name "*dan*" | grep '.html' or '.php' ???


What's the meaning of ??? at the end?

This should work just fine in your case with multiple patterns. You can add them by adding a backslash:
find . -type f -name "*dan*" | grep '.html\|.php' ???


What's the meaning of ??? at the end?

There is no need to pipe to grep.
find . -type f -name "*dan*" \( -path '*?html*' -o -path '*?php*' \)

Your grep '.html' would match html preceded with any character (as . in regex matches any character) anywhere in a line, this is why I used -path '*?html*' that does the same thing for pathnames used by find. Maybe this is what you meant, or maybe you really wanted the following:
find . -type f -name "*dan*" \( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.php' \)

where -name '*.html' matches literal .html (the dot is not special) at the end of filename.
